# Clean URLs in IIS with mod_rewrite

Tags: iis, mod-rewrite, isapi-rewrite

I have a mod_rewrite issue. Or more accurately, I have an issue with ISAPI_Rewrite, which is a mod_rewrite clone for IIS. Specifically, ISAPI_Rewrite v3 running on IIS 7. It aims to behave identically to mod_rewrite, so I hope my problem applies to mod_rewrite as well.

My problem boils down to this: I have a script `bar.php` which I want to access via the URL `foo`. I first rewrite `foo` to `bar`. Then try to convert the clean URL to a real file name.

```
RewriteRule ^foo$ bar

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule .* $0.php
```

The `RewriteCond` is failing because `${REQUEST_FILENAME}` still says "foo" rather than "bar". It is not updated after the first rewrite.

How can I make this work? I could fix this by simply writing `RewriteRule ^foo$ bar.php`. But I would strongly prefer to keep the URL remapping rules separate from the file extension rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tentative answer...

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$0.php -f
```

By using `$0` I get access to the latest rewritten URL, which makes me happy. But I have to add `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` to turn that into a file name, which makes me sad. Bit of a kludge.

Comment: Ah well, this is what I'm using barring any better answers!